# Can I control the handling of word files by the user in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, client-side

Today we have a classic asp application to manipulate the word files in the company. By using ActiveX, we can download, edit, print and finally upload the modifications without much interation.

Explaining: If I need to update anything in the "Processes.doc" file, I click on it, the ActiveX download the file to my desktop, I use it whenever I want but, when I close the file, the ActiveX uploads the new version, if this need applies with the rules.

This feature only works under IE and the users have this desire to do the same in other browsers. And the boss wants this system updated in asp.net.

My question is only "how is this possible?" How can I make it cross-plataform with the same usability that I have now? I spent the day reading about custom controls in asp.net (using object tag, but it don't work in FF), third-party components (expensive and I don't know if it will work), ActiveX written in .NET.

Any other suggestions? There is another way to this?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is being phased out as is Flash and being replaced by JS/HTML5. These two client side technologies are more than capable of editing word documents but in the end I think you'll find that getting away from a proprietary format like MS word is the way to go. HTML is powerful enough to provide most of the same features of MS word so once the files have been converted it's simply a matter of finding a javascript HTML document editor. From there you simply need to rework the mechanism which downloads and uploads the HTML to the server to use AJAX and you'll be good to go.

Here are some examples of HTML editors:

http://www.tinymce.com/
http://speckedit.com/demo
http://nicedit.com/demos.php
http://ckeditor.com/demo